# Run XJC with maven

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

I want simply generate ‌JAXB object with XJC. It's very easy with command line:

```
xjc -d generated-sources http://www.kbcafe.com/rss/atom.xsd.xml
```

Is there anyway to simply generate the source with Maven. I've tried to use jaxb2-maven-plugin and apache xcf but none of them worked. They did not support URL (just file) and when I put the file locally, it asks for remote resources and when I also download them, it says it has no permission to use XSD or DTD file locally! (I'm using Java8)

Comment: The last sentence... "it says" - Who is "it"? How does "it" say it?

Comment: The plugin! There's an issue for some XML tools with Java8, because of new Java8 security policy (as lexicore said)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of the [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

[`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) supports [compiling schemas from URLs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Specifying-What-To-Compile) OOTB.

However you may really want to make local copies of files to make your builds not Internet-dependent.

The issue you're probably running to with Java 8 is the new security policy. You can [disable XML security](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuring-Extension-Validation-and-XML-Security) in [`maven-jaxb2-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).

Finally, you're trying to compile the Aom schema. Here it is, [already compiled](https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/tree/master/atom/2005):

- https://github.com/highsource/w3c-schemas/tree/master/atom/2005

You may just use [existing Maven artifacts](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hisrc/w3c/atom-v_1_0/1.0.3/).

As for [jaxb2-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/jaxb2-maven-plugin), you may want to upgrade to the latest version. Lennart did a lot of work there so some of the features you may be missing might be already there. Version 2.0 might be released pretty soon.